# Recursive collection read in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, linked-list

I'm developing an application to read values from a Beckhoff PLC. The plc has a .net library that I can use to interface between my program and the PLC.

Each variable on the PLC is a symbol of type TcAdsSymbolInfo. This class has several members and one of them is a collection of TcAdsSymbolInfo and so on... You can see where this is going. Basically I have a tree structure with lots of symbols beeing that each one can have subsymbols. [**Beckhoff**](http://infosys.beckhoff.com/index.php?content=../content/1031/tc3_adsnetref/html/TwinCAT.Ads.TcAdsSymbolInfo.html&id=)

What I am trying to do is, for each symbol read all the subsymbols, this works if I do it by hand and just try to look on the first subsymbol level, but I really need all of them.

I tried to create a recursive function that receives a TcAdsSymbolInfo and on the end calls itself, but this throws a Stack Overflow Exception

```cs
    private void ReadSubsymbols(TcAdsSymbolInfo t)
    {
        if (t.SubSymbolCount > 0)
        {
            foreach (TcAdsSymbolInfo subsymbol in t.SubSymbols)
            {
                if (!symbols.ContainsKey(subsymbol.Name))
                    symbols.Add(subsymbol.Name, subsymbol);
                try
                {
                    ReadSubsymbols(subsymbol);
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString() + " - " + Ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

symbols is just a dictionary where I store the symbols name and the symbol itself.

Please try to abstract from the PLC part because I think this is just a pure logic/programming issue. I don't have any problems in communicating with the PLC or reading and writing values. The only issue is reading that structure.

Any seuggestions on I can do this maybe using a while or any other kind a loop? anything that does not throw an exception?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably search for tree traversal algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple tree walk. The basic logic is to start at the root:

- if the root is null, the tree is empty: we're done.
- if the root is non-null,

  - visit it
  - then recursively visit each of its children.

Easy. Mostly :D Where you'll get into trouble is when you encounter cycles in the graph (e.g., when a child node links back to one of its own parent nodes). If you have cycles, you'll have to track your visited nodes (as my example does) and check for cycles as you go (which my example does not do).

Given a class like this:

```
class SymbolInfo
{
  public string Name { get ; set ; }
  public SortedSet<SymbolInfo> Subsymbols { get ; set ; } 

  public SymbolInfo( string name )
  {
    this.Name = name ;
    this.Subsymbols = new SortedSet<SymbolInfo>( new SymbolInfo.Comparer() ) ;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return this.Name ?? "-null-" ;
  }

  private class Comparer : IComparer<SymbolInfo>
  {
    public int Compare( SymbolInfo x , SymbolInfo y )
    {
      return string.Compare(x.Name,y.Name,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ;
    }
  }
}
```

The tree walk looks something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> TreeWalk( SymbolInfo root , List<SymbolInfo> visited )
{
  if ( root != null )
  {
    visited.Add(root) ;
    yield return string.Join( " -> " , visited ) ;
    foreach ( SymbolInfo child in root.Subsymbols )
    {
      foreach ( string childPath in TreeWalk( child , visited ) )
      {
        yield return childPath ;
      }
    }
    visited.RemoveAt(visited.Count-1) ;
  }
}
```

And given a tree constructed like this:

```
private static SymbolInfo LoadTree()
{
  SymbolInfo a = new SymbolInfo("A") ;
  SymbolInfo b = new SymbolInfo("B") ;
  SymbolInfo c = new SymbolInfo("C") ;
  SymbolInfo d = new SymbolInfo("D") ;
  SymbolInfo e = new SymbolInfo("E") ;
  SymbolInfo f = new SymbolInfo("F") ;
  SymbolInfo g = new SymbolInfo("G") ;
  SymbolInfo h = new SymbolInfo("H") ;
  SymbolInfo i = new SymbolInfo("I") ;

  a.Subsymbols.Add(b) ;
  a.Subsymbols.Add(c) ;
  a.Subsymbols.Add(d) ;

  b.Subsymbols.Add(e) ;

  c.Subsymbols.Add(f) ;
  c.Subsymbols.Add(g) ;

  f.Subsymbols.Add(h) ;
  f.Subsymbols.Add(i) ;

  return a ;
}
```

We can invoke it like so:

```
SymbolInfo root = LoadTree() ;

foreach ( string path in TreeWalk( root , new List<SymbolInfo>() ) )
{
  Console.WriteLine(path) ;
}
```

To produced the following output:

```
A
A -> B
A -> B -> E
A -> C
A -> C -> F
A -> C -> F -> H
A -> C -> F -> I
A -> C -> G
A -> D
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I followed your sample and was able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use iterative tree traversal. 
But before attempting this **please make sure** the stack overflow is due to the recursion becoming too deep. There is a good chance that it is a **coding bug** allowing the recursion to go down infinitely.

You can do something like the following Psuedo code:

```
Push root node to stack

While (stack is not empty)
{
    current node = pop from stack
    process current node (and other processing goes here)

    add all children with nodes to stack
}
```

See this example that solves a similar problem with directories:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Comment: Additionally to what George said, you might want to pay attention whether you really have a tree only, or whether it is in reality a cyclical graph (aka a node having one of its ancestor nodes as a child), which could also explain the stack exhaustion.

Comment: This is a great iterative example. And, I agree, you must make sure that the stack overflow is directly resultant of the recursion calls. If not, the iterative approach will still run indefinitely. Chances are there is a Loop in the tree somewhere. You could avoid loops by storing and checking a reference to visited nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<TcAdsSymbolInfo> GetSymbols(IEnumerable<TcAdsSymbolInfo> set)
{
    if (!set.Any())
        return Enumerable.Empty<TcAdsSymbolInfo>();

    return set.SelectMany(sym => GetSymbols(sym.SubSymbols)));
}
```

You can then convert the result into your dictionary and check for dupes, etc.